# difference between the fgetc() and fgets()?

Tags: c, file

I am aware with the fact that `fgetc()` will read one character at a time from a file pointed by the `FILE` pointer which is used as argument.

`fgets()` will read the whole string upto the size specified in argument list but when end of line occurs `fgetc()` returns EOF while `fgets()` returns `NULL`.so why there are two confusing things to remember?

Comment: You just summarized two of the most-used functions in the C standard library, including comparative differences, in one sentence. What exactly is so "confusing" about them ?

Comment: Different people need different things, different situations need different tools, I guess that is all.

Comment: Should it be "end of **file** occurs, `fgetc()` returns EOF"?

Answer (score 14):

The reason one returns `EOF` while the other returns `NULL` is the difference in return types of the two functions: one returns an `int`, while the other returns a `char*`.

Both functions need to return a "special" value when the end of the input is reached. By "special" I mean a value that cannot appear in the input legally. For pointers, the special value in most cases is `NULL`, so that is what `fgets` returns. However, you cannot use `NULL` to mark the end of the input from `fgetc`, because character code of zero can legally appear in the input. That is why `EOF` is used as the "special value" in I/O functions that return a single character.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is probably something along the lines of "We didn't know C would become quite so popular for quite so long."

Other mistakes in the C standard include `creat()` (no e, why?), `strtok()` (thread-unsafe by default!), `sprintf()` (unlikely you'll use it without a possible buffer overrun, else it is too big a hammer anyway), `atoi()` (almost impossible to probably check for errors), and more!

Comment: See dasblinkenlight answer for explanation why fgetc/fgets difference was not a mistake.

Comment: Note that [`creat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/creat) is not in the C standard(-libraray), but in UNIX/POSIX.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: personally I think it's a bit of rationalization (however reasonable).  The API could have been made another way, for example fgetc() could return char*, NULL for EOF and otherwise a pointer to an internal (static like strtok!) array of two chars: the one from the stream followed by a \0 for convenience.  Then the two functions would return the same thing (a C string), and use the same sentinel value.  I'm not saying that would be a better API, but in the OP's framing of the question it might be a more consistent one.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to ask the original designers of the C standard library of course, not sure if any of them are around.

In my view, many standard functions that accept a string buffer return that same buffer, so from that point of view `fgets()`' behavior is totally regular and predictable.

If you're not afraid of `NULL`, the fact that it returns the pointer means the function can be chained:

```
char buf[128];
printf("you said '%s'\n", fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin));
```

The above is undefined if `fgets()` fails, but exchange `printf()` for something that has a well-defined handling of `NULL` and you see my point.

And it wouldn't make sense for `fgetc()` to return a pointer of course, since it's more low-level it just needs to return a single character or `EOF`, which `int` is the standard type for.

Comment: "something that has a well-defined handling of NULL" haha, you mean like almost none of the C standard library functions?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Perhaps, but you can write your own functions too. :)